# Default new record value from the table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

If I had a table called person with the fk `country_id`. 
Assuming that we have a table called country, which has a `default_country` column. And all rows except one (for USA), have `default_country` set to 0, only USA row has `default_country` to 1.

So if I m inserting person record, and I don't provide `country_id`, how can I default all new records to have `country_id` save with the id from row USA.

I know I can set a default column value to id (which I hardcode), but I don't know if its possible to get that from the table, here is what I mean:

```
"COUNTRY_ID" NUMBER(38,0) DEFAULT -1 CONSTRAINT PR_CN_NOT_NULL NOT NULL
```

-1 is the hardcoded. it would be nice if I could select it from country table using `default_country` flag rather than knowing the ID in advance, any ideas?

Comment: How about a trigger?

Comment: @mustaccio no can't do it. I mean I can, but I ll do this on the app end. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with `DEFAULT`. [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) says:

> Restrictions on Default Column Values
>   Default column values are
>   subject to the following restrictions:
>
> A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or
>   to other columns, the pseudocolumns LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date
>   constants that are not fully specified.
>
> The expression can be of any form except a scalar subquery expression.

So `DEFAULT (SELECT country_if FROM country where default_country =1 and rownum=1)`, and even  `DEFAULT (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)` fail because it cannot contain subquery .   You cannot work it around by defining your own function either.
The only way is to create row level before insert trigger .